# javascript - making a setTimeout inside a setTimeout to stop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code -

```
function example() {

    var i = 0;

    function add() {
        i++;
    }

    setTimeout(function doSomething() {
        add();
        setTimeout(doSomething, 1000);
    }, 1000);
}
```

Now basically I want by a pressed on a button to make the "setTimeout" to stop - any ideas how may i do that? 
thanks for any kind of help

Comment: have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.clearTimeout

Comment: If you're doing the same thing repeatedly, use `setInterval`.

Comment: ↑↑↑ `var interval = setInterval(add, 1000);` and call `clearInterval(interval);` on button click BUT be aware of context, you may want to remove example function context or set `interval` on global context (e.g, removing `var` on declaration)

Answer (score 2):

You need not to call `setTimeout` inside `setTimeout`. You can use `setInterval`, it will call for every second. see below code to stop interval using `clearInterval()`

```
var timeInterval = '';
function example() {

    var i = 0;

    function add() {
        i++;
    }

    //store time Interval  using variable
    timeInterval = setInterval(function() {
        add();
        //setTimeout(doSomething, 1000);-- remove this
    }, 1000);
}

function buttonClick()
{
  //clear time out
  window.clearInterval(timeInterval);
}
```

Comment: no, `setTimout` executes once. did you mean to change it for a `setInterval`?

Comment: Then there is no point of naming function `doSomething` (is there any???) in this example, anyway +1

Answer (score 0):

You need to use clearTimeout:

```
var timer = setTimeout(doSomething, 1000); //store setTimeout in a variable
//now when you need clear it:
clearTimeout(timer)
```

Answer (score -1):

To clear the the delay caused by "setTimeout" use "clearTimeout" function.
[Check Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers)